# "Whether" followed by a preposition

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> Whether in Los Angeles or in New York, house prices are very high.

Is this sentence correct? Can "Whether" be followed by a preposition?

If not, if I want to mention the two cities, what word or phrase should I use?

Comment: Be it in Los Angeles or New York, house prices are very high.

Comment: House prices are very high, whether it is in Los Angeles or New York.

Comment: It's acceptable. You could also say "Whether it is / it be in Los Angeles or in New York, house prices are very high.

Comment: I guess generally a clause needs to follow "whether“, but then we can kinda omit "it is", then it reaches the current form.

Comment: **Whether** is also used in other sense, it might be misinterpreted.

Comment: Whether up a tree, or in my pocket, a squirrel is a wonderful creature.

Comment: @Sam What other sense? I don't see one.

Comment: @gotube it can be used in **if** sense.

Comment: @Sam What do you mean "if" sense? "Whether" only indicates the choice between two alternatives. It cannot mean "if".

Comment: @gotube Did you ask whether(=if) they were going?(whether not only express choice, but also an inquiry or Investigation .)

Comment: @Sam It's like the two equations 2+2=4 and 2x2=4. You cannot say that "+" sometimes means "x". It's the same with "whether" and "if". They come to the same result if used in a yes/no context, but they don't have the same function.

Comment: Whether(=if) in Los Angeles or in New York, house prices are very high.(This is incorrect )(difficult for a beginner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to answer my own question.

In [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228258), 8a has examples

> Whether it is fair, or whether it is wet, he pursues his labours with
> equal success.
>
> For Loyalty is still the same, Whether it win or lose
> the Game.

In this sense, a complete sentence must follow "whether".

Then in the sense of 8b, the sentences can have ellipsis. In this case "whether" is often virtually equivalent to "either".

> William, whether by accident or by design, was not admitted.
> (**preposition**)
>
> The increase in the number of officials.., which should give pause to
> every man, whether Liberal or Tory. (**noun**)